# look up any number in a text field

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column that has plain text data. I am looking to find any name that is followed by an integer 'Sam 123', Sam 597" etc.

I have tried

```
SELECT message, LENGTH(message)
FROM surveys
WHERE LENGTH(MESSAGE) = 6
```

but it returns alphanumeric data.

Comment: Can you give a sample record or two, and then the output of your select?

Comment: Hi Gordon and thank you for your response. Here is a sample data:                                   Suervey_code Message
1521         Need a refund on sale Sam 12305
1523         Didn't get a receipt, bought product Sam 54895 2 weeks ago
2457         $200 overcharge on sale Sam 87456
5644         Processed credit card twice on order Sam 11688

Answer (score 1):

Starting on DB2 11.1 you can use regular expressions. Your query should look like:

```
select message, length(message)
  from surveys
  where regexp_like(message, '[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+')
```

This regular expression matches:

- One or more letters, followed by
- A single space, followed by
- One or more digits.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I have the 10.1 version and your code gave me a SQL00199N error.

Answer (score 1):

For all DB2 versions:

```
select message
from table(values 'Sam 123', 'Sam 597', 'Sam123', 'Sam', '123 Sam') t(message)
where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($s, "[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+")' passing t.message as "s") as int) = 1
```